# JQuery Hotkeys Passing from properties file

Tags: jquery

I have a properties file which contains the keys like

```
home= 'ctrl+home'
save= 'ctrl+s'
```

These properties I want to pass to the hotkeys using jquery  like

```
$(document).bind('keystrokes', {
    keys: ['alt+n']

}, function(event){ 
     var newInq=document.getElementById('header:agxheader:newinq');

     if(newInq!=null)
         newInq.click();
     else
       return false;
});
```

in the place of `keys['alt+n']` can I pass the value dynamically from properties file like
keys [save].
any ideas how this can be implemented.

Thanks for the responses.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to have a Json property file format:

```
  { 
      "commands": [ 
          {
              "title": "home", 
              "action":"ctrl+home",
              "event":"yourEvent"
          }, 
          {
              "title": "save", 
              "action": "ctrl+s",
              "event":"yourEvent"
          }
       ] 
    }
```

Then you can use: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/ to get the "data" object and finally, when you will have your object:

```
for(var o in obj.commands){
    $(document).bind('keystrokes', { 
        keys: [obj.commands[o].action]
    }, function(event){ obj.commands[o].yourEvent};
}
```

Comment: but my project requirement is reading from msg.properties file

Comment: i tried with jquery internationalization  using jquery.i18n.properties.js .  in this case i am able access the properties but while passing to the keys array the key was unable to fire the event . ref: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-i18n-properties/            thanks for the response